# React Hook "useCourtClock" cannot be called inside a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my component:

```
const handleSubmit = useCallback(
    event => {
      event.preventDefault()
      onDraft(id)
    },
    [id, onDraft]
  )

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div
       
      >
        <Button type="submit" mode="strong" wide >
          Click
        </Button>
      </div>
     
    </form>
  )
```

I need to now add something when `handleSubmit` gets called. Above the `onDraft` function, I want to add `const { test } = useClock()` , but it says:

> React Hook "useCourtClock" cannot be called inside a callback.

How do I fix this ? Mainly, I need `useClock` to be called when user clicks on the button, because I want to know if anything has changed before he clicks on the button.

Comment: Have you tried instantiating your clock at the top of the function/class declaration, and then calling it by using whatever variable you declared as needed? This sounds similar to what you need to do with redux and useDispatch() since it's also a hook; you have to instantiate the dispatch at the top of the function, and then call that variable when you need it.

Comment: Assuming you're using [this site](https://github.com/rafaelquintanilha/use-clock), looks like it declares the useClock before declaring anything like a handleSubmit or a return, and then grabs `time` when it needs it. Are you getting the current time in handleSubmit if you do it this way?

Comment: I think you're right. I had a feeling that putting `useClock` above the `callback` would cause showing old values while clicking on `handleSubmit` when user didn't refresh the page. but it turns out it's still showing updated version

Comment: But this happens, because I call the component function every 10 seconds, so `useClock` would return updated value,  and handleSubmit would use it successfully. but the problem is during these 10 seconds, `useClock` will return old value and `handleSubmit` will use the old value instead of using the updated one. makes sense ?

Comment: Surprisingly, it still works. Great. Not a react developer, so just fixing stuff and not fully understanding it. Thanks a lot for the advice